# Cannot find module 'gulp-gitinfo'

Tags: gulp

today I recived an error that say to me that gulp-gitinfo is not find in file

> module.js:491
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-gitinfo'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (E:\pcs_baku\PCS.Web\Public\gulpfile.js:24:17)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\andrejgo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
>       at Liftoff. (C:\Users..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:198:16)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:17:3)
>       at Liftoff. (C:\Users..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:190:9)

Some help, what can I do?
Thanks

Comment: npm install gulp-gitinfo --save-dev; or
bower i gulp-gitinfo --save

Comment: my bad => npm install, *solved*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm install gulp-gitinfo --save-dev;

or bower i gulp-gitinfo --save